Stop AlwaysOn service and SQL Server
I have an AlwaysOn configuration with 3 servers, two of them in synchronous mode with two Availability Groups, and the third server is in asynchronous mode because it is located in a remote site.
Due to network maintenance tasks, the communication between them will be affected for a period of 30 to 40 minutes, maybe less, but I would like to know if this time could somehow break the AlwaysOn configuration, or if you recommend stopping the SQL Server service until the maintenance tasks are finished and then starting it again.
Thank you very much for your help.

If you aren't doing much during the time of the maintenance on the primary replica (aka workload that changes data), then it shouldn't cause a problem (except to monitoring software) with the connectivity being down, assuming quorum is kept.
SQL Server will notice the connection failure and retry the connection, periodically. Eventually when the network is back up, the secondary will connect (assuming the network maintenance is completed correctly) back to the primary and they should start synchronizing again.
If you do have workload, then it's up to you to decide if that workload is low enough that it won't cause a problem - such as the log has enough space and the network has enough throughput to catch the replica back up.
You absolutely can remove the replica from the availability group and once the maintenance is done add it back in. Chances are it'll need to be manually caught up via log restores before it'll sync back.
